# Valid workaround for <style> tags inside of <body> to add custom CSS?

Tags: html, css, validation, stylesheet

I know putting `<style>` tags inside of `<body>` is not valid. **What other techniques are possible to get around this limitation?**

In my design I have a few static pages created with server side includes. For each page I need a few extra lines of CSS to control the display of a few DIVs.

What is the best **valid** way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use javascript inside `<script>` tags that insert a css `<link>` element into the page that should then load the associated stylesheet

Comment: Users with JavaScript disabled would be adversely affected by a JS-only solution.

Comment: @Andy E - Correct, but you can't always support everyone.

Comment: This was a good solution, however I ended up splitting my server-side include files so I could put custom values in the <head> element of every page.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a few DIVs and just a few styles, use the *style* attribute.  Sure, it's not ideal, but it's valid.

```
<div style="position: relative; width:200px; height:100px;">etc...</div>
```

Comment: The div's are inside of my static includes, but depending on the page that is using the include, I want to make the CSS style dynamic.